# Stuck on a While-Loop Example

Tags: python, while-loop

Why is the value 22 of the index element [0]  added to the sum in the code below?
Isn't `i` in this code always `< 5` because `i = i -1` ?

```
numbers = [22, 34, 12, 32, 4]
sum = 0

i = len(numbers)

while (i != 0):
   i -= 1
   sum = sum + numbers[i]

print "The sum is: ", sum
```

Comment: yes, i is always less tha 5, but 0 is also less than 5

Comment: does the question make sense? As `numbers[0]=22` and `i<5`, the value `22` is, of course, always added to the sum.

Comment: Why not use `sum(numbers[1:])` ? Also, you should not use `sum` as a variable name since it overwrites the built-in sum function!

Comment: Am learning Python now, so don't be mad I asked the question. Thanks!

Comment: For cases like this the [Online Python Tutor](http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit) gives a nice visual aid to help you understand what's going on.

Comment: or this ... http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum

Answer (score 3):

```
i = 5

while (i != 0) --> i=5
i-=1 --> i=4
sum = sum+numbers[4]

while (i != 0) --> i=4
i-=1 --> i=3
sum = sum+numbers[3]

while (i != 0) --> i=3
i-=1 --> i=2
sum = sum+numbers[2]

while (i != 0) --> i=2
i-=1 --> i=1
sum = sum+numbers[1]

while (i != 0) --> i=1
i-=1 --> i=0
sum = sum+numbers[0]

while (i != 0) --> i=0 so it'll stop.
```

As you can see ,numbers[0] will be added.

Comment: At the beginning you could easily write these algorithms value and output on paper. It'll help you get the catch

Answer (score 3):

You could re-arrange you code (without changing it's behaviour) as:

```
while (i != 0):
    sum = sum + numbers[i-1]
    i -= 1
```

Which makes it clear that `numbers[0]` is being added to sum.

However, you should not be using `sum` as variable name, as it overwrites the (useful) built-in function, which, for example, enables you to write your code much more concisely as:

```
sum(numbers[1:]) #sum of everything in list except 1st element
```